# Use a struct to add variables to the login information?

Tags: authentication, coldfusion, passwords

I'm trying to use a struct to arrange three sets of logins and passwords.  Ideally, I would like to have the form.password and the form.username check the variables of the structs userOne through userThree rather than just only checking one instance of a password and username.

Can anyone point me the direction of what I need to know/look at in order to make this happen?

Thank you in advance.

```
<cfset userOne = structNew()>
<cfset userOne.name = "cat">
<cfset userOne.password = "meow">
<cfset userOne.group = "1">

<cfset userTwo = structNew()>
<cfset userTwo.name = "bird">
<cfset userTwo.password = "chirp">
<cfset userTwo.group = "2">

<cfset userThree = structNew()>
<cfset userThree.name = "mouse">
<cfset userThree.password = "squeak">
<cfset userThree.group = "3">

 <cfset this_password = "squeak">
   <cfif form.password neq "squeak" or form.username neq "mouse">
    <cflocation url="login.cfm?status=le">
         <cfelse>
       <cflock scope="session" timeout="10">
         <cfset session.valid_user = "yes">
       </cflock>
    <cflocation url="index.cfm" addtoken="no">
 </cfif>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfset userOne = structNew()>
<cfset userOne.name = "cat">
<cfset userOne.password = "meow">
<cfset userOne.group = "1">

<cfset userTwo = structNew()>
<cfset userTwo.name = "bird">
<cfset userTwo.password = "chirp">
<cfset userTwo.group = "2">

<cfset userThree = structNew()>
<cfset userThree.name = "mouse">
<cfset userThree.password = "squeak">
<cfset userThree.group = "3">

 <cfset this_password = "squeak">
   <cfif NOT (authUser(userOne, form.username, form.password)
        OR authUser(userTwo, form.username, form.password)
        OR authUser(userThree, form.username, form.password))>
    <cflocation url="login.cfm?status=le">
         <cfelse>
       <cflock scope="session" timeout="10">
         <cfset session.valid_user = "yes">
       </cflock>
    <cflocation url="index.cfm" addtoken="no">
 </cfif>


<cffunction name="authUser" access="public" output="false" returntype="boolean">
    <cfargument name="user"        type="struct" required="true">
    <cfargument name="username" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="password" type="string" required="true">
    <cfreturn (arguments.user.name EQ arguments.username) AND (arguments.user.password EQ arguments.password)>
</cffunction>
```

This will work but it is a little messy. I hope this is just an example of you problem and not how it works.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  What do you mean by how it works?  I'm ultimately wanting to restrict one user to just a folder on the server, while the other two users have access to the entire site, but was first hoping to establish the three users and their logins.

Comment: I really meant that defining users in code is messy. Also, it is usually a little more readable if the true case is first then the false case when doing if statements. But your logic is sound. I hope my post helped you a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you can nest your 3 user structures inside a users struct, keyed by name, then you can perform a `structKeyExists()` to find a matching user, then simply check the password. Heaps quicker than looping over many structures, one by one.

eg.

```
<cfscript>
users = {
    cat = { name: "cat", password: "meow", group: 1 },
    bird = { name: "bird", password: "chirp", group: 2 },
    mouse = { name: "mouse", password: "squeak", group: 3 }
};

if (
    structKeyExists( form, 'username' )
    && structKeyExists( form, 'password' )
    && len( form.username & form.password ) > 0
    && structKeyExists( users, form.username )
    && structKeyExists( users[form.username], 'password' )
    && users[form.username].password == form.password
) {
    // sign them in
}
else {
    // throw error "invalid username or password"
}
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of handling this:

```
<cfscript>
users = [{
    username = "cat",
    password = "meow"
},{
    username = "bird",
    password = "chirp"
},{
    username = "mouse",
    password = "squeak"
}];

for (user in users) {
    if (user.username == form.username && user.password == form.password) {
        // handle success log in
        // redirect
    }
}

// handle invalid log in
// redirect
</cfscript>
```